# Express validator can't use .default()

Tags: express, validation

I'm writing an Express Validator validation and sanitization chain. It works, but `default()` seems to defy me.

```
[
  body('page')
    .exists()
    .default(20)
    .isInt({ min: 0 })
    .withMessage(SystemService.errorResponse('errors.users.page_001'))
    .toInt()
]
```

This is supposed to be correct, but it's not.

```
TypeError: express_validator_1.body(...).optional(...).default is not a function
```

The error is detected by VSCode too:

```
[ts] Property 'default' does not exist on 'ValidationChain'
```

It doesn't matter where I put it in the chain, or if there are other methods.

What am I doing wrong? Other sanitization chain methods like `toInt()` all work, only `default()` causes this error.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue. Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example?

Comment: This is all the example I can give. It simply doesn't work. Nothing is supposed to be imported to make default() work, so I'm really at a loss. Maybe Typescript is the reason?

Comment: You could provide a script with a simple Express app exposing a single endpoint using the validation chain in the question. I tried to do the same but couldn't reproduce the issue.

Comment: What version of `express-validator` are you using? I seemed to be able to get your code to work as-is with the latest version.

Comment: Have you tried to print the object in the console to see whether default even exists in it?